# how to make a basic swift 4 socket io app

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I have been trying to make a basic swift 4 app that connects to my node server and runs the events that I have for a web version of this app. With the code below, it seamlessly connects to the server without a hitch, but on the other hand, I can obviously not emit to the socket outside of this closure because the socket is defined with `viewDidLoad()`.

If I try to move the socket declaration outside of this function, it gives me this error:

> "Cannot use instance member 'manager' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available".

I have attempted to look at many different documentations, returning with no success.

```
@IBOutlet weak var messagesBody: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var newMessageInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var newMessageSubmit: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/chat.html?name=developer&room=test")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    let socket = manager.defaultSocket

    socket.connect()

    newMessageSubmit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendNewMessage), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func sendNewMessage() {
    let newMessageContent = newMessageInput.text!
    print("Sending message..." + newMessageContent)
    // socket.emit("createMessage", newMessageContent)
    // right here ^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as the error says, you can't use manager instance property outside of `viewDidLoad`to initiate socket, if you want to access a variable in any method you must declare it global so its scope is the entire class. This code does with `socket` variable:

```
var socket:SocketIOClient!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/chat.html?name=developer&room=test")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])

   self.socket = manager.defaultSocket

   self.socket.connect()

   newMessageSubmit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendNewMessage), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func sendNewMessage() {

   let newMessageContent = newMessageInput.text!

   print("Sending message..." + newMessageContent)

   self.socket.emit("createMessage", newMessageContent)

}
```

Comment: An answer is more helpful (both to the author of the question and to future readers) if it *explains* the problem and the solution, instead of posting just a code dump.

Comment: @Sh_Khan at each reference of self.socket it says: Value of optional type 'SocketIOClient?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: convert to var socket:SocketIOClient!